# How to perform same calculations over several matrices?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I've `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, etc as `igraph` objects.

This is my code:

```
setwd("D:\\Educacion\\PeerEffects\\matriz de contactos\\Intentos\\")
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern="matriz+.*dta")
list(filenames)
names <-substr(filenames,1,7)
for(i in names) 
  {
  filepath <- file.path("D:/Educacion/PeerEffects/matriz de contactos/Intentos",paste(i,".dta",sep=""))
  assign(i, read.dta(filepath))
}

for (i in 1:length(names)){
  assign(paste0("A", i), unname(as.matrix(get(paste0("matriz", i)))))
  assign(paste0("B", i), graph.adjacency(get(paste0("A", i)), mode = "directed", weighted = NULL, diag = FALSE))
}
```

This is what I need to do to every igraph objetc B1, B2, etc. where "matrices" should be the list of igraph objetcs:

```
for (i in matrices) {
  average.path.length(i)
  diameter(i)
  transitivity(i)
  degree(i)
}
```

This is the error I get when matrices is a list of names (B1, B2, etc):
Error in average.path.length(i) : Not a graph object

Comment: Please add this error to your original post. Also, as it is, your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Honestly it is not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe you should specify well, provide some (reproducible) code and a desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the variable called 'matrix1', use `get`

```
m <- get(paste0('matrix', i))
```

Then do all your things like `degree(m)`, ...

Though as I mentioned in your previous question, it would be better if `matrices` was the list of *igraph objects*, rather than the list of *names* of the objects. Then your current code would work as-is, and you would have functions like `lapply` available to you.

---

Update: re your assigning code.

You could do this many ways, but the common element is that instead of storing your variables in A1, ..., A100 , you store them in a list `A` so that `A[[1]]` is your old A1.

e.g.

```
As <- lapply(names,
             function (name) {
                 filepath <- ...
                 as.matrix(read.dta(filepath)) # this is Ai
              })
# note As[[i]] is your old Ai

Bs <- lapply(As, graph.adjacency, mode="directed", weighted = NULL, diag = FALSE)
# now Bs[[i]] is your old Bi
```

And you could do e.g.

```
avg.lengths <- lapply(Bs, average.path.length)
degree <- lapply(Bs, degree)
```

and so on. Then for graph `i` you could use `Bs[[i]]` to get the graph, `avg.lengths[[i]]` to get the avg length, etc.

If `average.path.length`, `diameter`, `transitivity`, and `degree` all return SINGLE values, you could simply store them in a dataframe:

```
graph.properties <- data.frame(
                        graph=1:length(Bs),
                        average.path.length=sapply(Bs, average.path.length),
                        diameter=sapply(Bs, diameter),
                        ...)
```

Then `graph.properties$diameter[i]` is the diameter of `Bi`. However you can't store the graphs themselves in a dataframe, as dataframe cells should contain single values only not complicated objects.

Also I think `degree` returns a numeric vector, so you're stuck with a list rather than dataframe (hence my use of `lapply` initially rather than `sapply`).

Comment: Yes I think that is the problem I am having. But how do I make a list of the igraph objetcs?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you are creating each of your `matrix`i-s.

Comment: I edited my question and added the preceeding part of the code. Note that  I changed matrix1, matrix2, etc for B1,B2, etc.